# Traveling from nonschengen to schengen with my EU passport

Tags: passport-stamps

Will my EU passport get stamped..traveling from a non schengen/European country upon arrival at munich airport germany?

And also if im going to a nonschengen/european country will i get a stamp on exit from my country/swe

Answer (score 5):

No. EU states do not stamp EU passports.

Comment: They also rarely stamp other passports actually which surprised me

Comment: @MattDouhan I have found that the diligence about stamping other passports depends on the particular border post.  I doubt that Munich airport is at all lax about it.

Comment: so did I until my gf at the time from NZ did not get a stamp and had to ask for it, maybe the guy at the desk had a bad day I don’t know